# redirect with path ends in redirect loop on openshift

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, openshift, http-redirect

i am having a weird issue making a redirect to another domain with a parth at the end on my express app on openshift.

i have a domain which is my default domain and other secondary domains so i want to redirecct all requests to secondary domains to my main domain.

i have this very simplified handler written in coffeescript where i redirect to the `/admin` path

```
app.get '/admin', (req, res) ->
  if not req.headers.host.match(/maindomain\.com/)
    return res.redirect('http://www.maindomain.com/admin')
  res.send('hello world!!!!')
```

what happens here is that i end in a redirect loop like the location header would never change and it loops forever
the funny thing is that the redirect works fine if i just redirect the domain without a path.

so redirect from `secondarydomain.com` -> `maindomain.com` works fine (?!)

i do not understand why this is happening.
of course i thought it might be caused by openshift and or haproxy which runs in front of my app but i couldn't figure this out yet...

any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this is an issue on openshift side. it seems like how their internal routing 'smartness' is configured it doesn't allow a redirect to another alias of the same application and it ends in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
/mymaindomain\.com/.test('http://www.maindomain.com/admin')
>>> false
```

thus when you redirect, the destination url triggers the condition and redirects...

maybe you want `/maindomain\.com/` ?

Comment: no that was a mispelling in my question... but thank you